# Access to elements of .fla from secondary .as

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to access to the elements of the .fla (like buttons, textfields, etc.) from other .as, not the main class.

EDIT: I am going to share the code for more info.

I have a gallery.fla which document class is gallery.as. The code is not important, there I read a XML and depends of the value of some tag I want to another class modify the label of a button on gallery.fla

gallery.as

```
package{
import otherClass; 
public class gallery() extends MovieClip{
    private var otherGallery:otherClass = new otherClass();
    public function gallery(){
          if(x="xmlValue"){
             otherGallery.changeLabel();
          }     
     }
 }  
}
```

otherClass.as

```
public function changeLabel():void{
  btnOpen.label = "labelChanged";
}
```

btnOpen its a button on .fla, I can't access any element of .fla from otherClass.as. ERROR 1120: Access of undefined property btnOpen.

Comment: You need to precisely determine the hierarchy of your components. Also the answer depends on how does the "external .as" appears in launched Flash app.

Comment: you should really try something.

Comment: Let's see, i'll be more specific. I have a .fla with buttons and stuff and depends some condition I use a .as or another .as, but I can't access to the property of the elements from there.

Comment: You need to try something and share the code then only we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of scope.  All objects in AS3 are classes, and in programming vars and instances are only available in their scope.

There are few ways you can go about getting a reference to the main timeline's scope from one of it's children.

**1.  The easy sloppy way**

You can gain a reference to the main timeline/document class with the `root` keyword.

```
MovieClip(root).btnOpen.label = "labelChanged";
```

The root var becomes available *AFTER* the class has been added to the display.

**2. Pass a reference to the main timeline/document class to your other classes**

So, in your Main.as (or main timeline, or document class) you could do something like this:

```
myGalleryInstance.main = this;
```

Then your `gallery` class would look like this:

```
//those parenthesis don't belong in the class declaration --> () <--, I've taken them out
public class gallery extends MovieClip {
    private var otherGallery:otherClass; //better to instantiate complex objects in the constructor
    public var main:MovieClip; //create a public var you can populate

    public function gallery(){
          otherGallery = new otherClass();
          if(x="xmlValue"){
             otherGallery.changeLabel();
          }     
    }

    public function changeLabel():void{
        main.btnOpen.label = "labelChanged";
    }
}
```

**3. Use The Parent Keyword - Sloppy way #2**

If you `gallery` class and `otherCLass` are display objects, you can use the `parent` keyword to get the Main class /main timeline.  So assuming gallery is a child of the main timeline and otherClass is a child of gallery,  from gallery.as you'd do:

```
//the main timeline is the grandparent of 'this' (otherClass)
MovieClip(MovieClip(parent).parent).btnOpen.label = "labelChanged";
```

Like `root`, `parent` is only available after the object has been added to the display.

Comment: Well, I tried those 3 options and the first one works fine for me. Thanks!